# Possible to redirect incoming messages to another application?

Tags: android, sms

I have a question. Is it possible to either redirect incoming messages to another application or allow the other application to receive the sms as well? If there is, can someone post up a link or a tutorial? Couldn't find anything on the internet pertaining to my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want receive sms in same device than you can use database as sms comes you can store it to database and retrive in another app.other thing if you want to send sms to other device than you can redirect to other device number as you got the sms.

Comment: The sending of my sms is done already. Is there a tutorial on how to insert the incoming message into the database and then retrieving it?

Comment: Or is there a ContentProvider for the sms that I can use?

Comment: You can receive sms and get all the details in smsReceive class by extend BroadcastReceiver after getting all details you can store into your database by creating it.The link below will be useful http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/

Comment: I dun really understand though... Can give me a brief explanation?

Comment: let me know in which portion or functionality you really like to explanation.

Comment: Thanks but i think i get how it works. Its the same as the recieving of sms. But what I want to know is wow to retrieve the sms from the built-in inbox and the send it to my application's inbox? I realise that using database is the best way but I read from online sources saying that using the content provider for sms is not a good idea at all.